# JS - dynamic inserting items into array on button click

Tags: javascript

So while creating a project I've encounter a problem. I have a container, let's call it container with assigned index, so it looks like `container0` etc. Inside that container I have buttons to copy ( and delete ) this particular segment with all it's data. I also have index array to make sure all id's are unique. I have a working project, but I want to solve this particular situation, when I have multiple containers, and in page source containers have indexes like `[0,1,5,8,6,7,9,12,10,11]`. What I am doing right now is whenever somebody clicks button inside let's say container[7] and user wants to copy that container 3 times I will have `[0,1,5,8,6,7,13,14,15,9,12,10,11]`, and the way I've solved this problem is inside button handler I get id of container like `const index = parseInt(e.target.id.match(/\d+/)[0]);` and then using `querySelector` I select which container I want to get data from. What I would like for you to help me figure out, how may I get container Id inside which button was clicked in different, easier way instead of matching id from button ( copy and delete button also have id, which is equal to container id). Also one more thing, I use `eventDelegetion` to add `eventListeners` for newly created segments.

Comment: Use a `data-container="7"` attribute and then use `e.target.dataset.container` to get the value.

Comment: hey @Barmar thanks for your reply. One thing to consider, I would have to use e.target.closest('container').dataset.container, so I don't think your solution might help solving my issue :)

Comment: Why do you need `.closest`? If you're currently using the ID of the target, why can't you just add the `data-container` attribute to that same target?

Comment: If you want more than just general advice, you need to post a [mcve].

Comment: @Barmar hm, that's valid point, thanks for that! By the way, is it bad practice to extract id like I did ? About reproducible example, I don't want to paste like 80% of application here so that's why I ask for general advice ;)

Comment: You don't have to paste 80% of the application, that's why we ask for a *minimal* example. Just the part that's directly relevant to the question.

Comment: Lots of applications use the technique you describe. I personally dislike it, but if it works for you, fine.

Comment: @Barmar I might have to paste most of it, because I use vanillaJS throughout entire application to add/remove elements on the page dynamically, so I will have to paste html, js to generate segment, button events etc. If it works and "it's fine" it's fine for me as well. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.